# "wget --mirror" Alternative

Tags: backup, ssh, wget, mirror

I'm looking for an alternative to using this, it doesn't have to use FTP, but it should provide the same functionality as the "--mirror" option of wget where it only downloads new and changed files.

```
wget --mirror --preserve-permissions --directory-prefix=/hdd2/website-backups --exclude-directories=special,stats --ftp-user=user --ftp-password=pass ftp://ftp.domain.com
```

Currently the above command is how a remote site is being backed up every few days via cron job on a home server. The remote site has moved to a new host with SSH available and I've already got public/private keys setup for SSH. Now I would like to use something a little more secure than wget/ftp for the automated backup, but since this site has a lot of image files most of which will not change, I don't really want to zip up the entire documentRoot and download it every time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[rsync](http://samba.anu.edu.au/rsync/) is the standard utility for this:

```
rsync -avz -e ssh source/ user@destServer:/dest/
```

- a For archive, keeps permissions,
  type stamps, etc.
- v for verbose
- e ssh , use over ssh
- z for compression, if you want that.  It won't try to re-compress archive (zip) files.

rsync generally comes with Linux distributions.  It also meets your requirement of not transferring things that have not changed.

Comment: +1 for rsync. Here are a few useful rsync flags: when you are running rsync interactively (mostly during testing) use the **--progress** flag. Some informative statistics can be gathered by using the **--stats** flag. Also, if you _dont_ want rsync to hog all of your bandwidth you can limit its download rate by using **--bwlimit=KBPS** KBytes per second. I also find it useful to use the -e parameter when I have to use a nonstandard ssh port like this **-e"
ssh -p 10222"**

Comment: Mention of the -e flag when non-standard ports are being used also definitely comes in handy. :)